# Add a Movable textbox via React Native

Tags: react-native

**Movable textbox via React Native**

I need to add movable textbox on my Main Screen, which is movable means user can change its position or move it anywhere on Main Screen.

Please suggest me way which control i need to use and how it achieved.

Thanks in advance for your guidance.

Comment: You probably couldn't find examples because the default terminology for what you want is "Draggable". There's [one tutorial](https://moduscreate.com/animated_drag_and_drop_with_react_native/) 
 on it.

Comment: I want to make a cheque printing app, Someone Said me, use div ...